# Как создать лист сразу с предзаполненными классами?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Мы можем создать лист:

```
List<MyClass> LC = new List<MyClass>();
```

*MyClass* представляет собой:

```
private class MyClass 
{
    public string A { get; set; };
    public string B { get; set; };
    public string C { get; set; };
}
```

Обычно мы делаем заполнение класса как-то так

```
for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
{
    var tmp = new MyClass()
    {
        A = "ABC",
        C = "DIG",
    }
    LC.Add(tmp);
}
```

А можно ли, зная кол-во классов в листе и зная константные элементы класса "ABC" и "DIG" сразу создать нужное кол-во заполненных классов?
Т.е. убрать множественный вызов `Add()`?

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос, чем именно показанный код вас не устраивает?

Comment: Да. Можно. Посмотрите как создавать списки

Comment: @AzizUmarov можете привести пример - как лучше это реализовать?

Comment: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-list

Comment: Вот так можно `List<MyClass> LC = Enumerable.Range(0, 300).Select(x => new MyClass { A = "ABC", C = "DIG" }).ToList();`. Но это по сути тот же цикл, делает похожую работу, только записан по-другому. К сожалению, чтобы создать 300 экземпляров класса - нужно создать 300 экземпляров класса. Ну или я все еще не понимаю вопрос.

Comment: `public string A { get; set; } = "ABC";` ?

Comment: @aepot вы ошибаетесь, т.к. команда Add внутри вашего варианта вызывается единожды

Comment: @aepot вообще - это почти то, что я искал

Comment: Метод `Add` в коде на основе Linq, который я показал, вообще ни разу не вызывается. Там другая механика работает, но внутри этот код - все тот же цикл.

Comment: Опишите подробнее, что вам нужно, чего хотите добиться, от чего избавиться? Возможно, вам нужна структура вместо класса: тогда можно создать один её экземпляр и добавлять в список (при этом автоматически будут создаваться копия). Возможно, вам нужно указать ёмкость списка при создании: `new List<MyClass>(300)` - при этом не будет перевыделяться новая память при добавлении элементов в него.

Comment: В упор не хотите `Add` - используйте массив вместо списка. И назначайте элементы массива по индексатору.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы хотите убрать множественный вызов `Add`. В этом есть резон, потому что память для списка будет перевыделяться и данные копироваться в новую область памяти, когда ёмкости (Capacity) списка окажется недостаточно. Чтобы избежать этого, нужно создать список с нужной ёмкостью:

```
new List<MyClass>(300)
```

Теперь вызовы метода `Add` всегда имеют сложность O(1).

---

Свойству можно назначить инициализатор:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string A { get; set; } = "ABC";
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; } = "DIG";
}
```

Теперь код будет выглядеть так:

```
var tmp = new MyClass();
list.Add(tmp);

// или так
list.Add(new MyClass());
```

Но следует помнить, что теперь эти свойства всегда будут иметь значение по умолчанию при создании, если их не изменить явно.

---

Возможно, вам подойдёт структура вместо класса (вообще, для хранения *данных* структуры почти всегда предпочтительней):

```
struct MyStruct
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
}
```

Тогда код с её применением будет выглядеть так:

```
var list = new List<MyStruct>(300);
            
var tmp = new MyStruct { A = "ABC", C = "DIG" };

for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
{
    list.Add(tmp);
}
```

Создаём один экземпляр структуры с заполненными свойствами. Далее добавляем этот экземпляр - т. к. это *значимый* тип, создаются копии.

---

Если даже создание списка с заданной ёмкостью вас почему-то не устраивает и хочется непременно избавиться от метода `Add`, то предлагаю использовать массив.

```
var array = new MyClass[300];

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    var tmp = new MyClass { A = "ABC", C = "DIG" };
    array[i] = tmp;
}
```

Вуаля! Вместо добавления в список используем назначение элемента по индексу.
Вместе с массивом можно использовать как классы, так и структуры.

---

Напоследок отмечу, что применение LINQ: `Enumerable.Range. ... .ToList()` не избавляет от *добавления* элементов в список. Просто оно явно не видно, но внутри происходит. Причём производительность этого способа хуже.

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример [отсюда](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-list)

```
var students = new List<Student>() { 
            new Student(){ Id = 1, Name="Bill"},
            new Student(){ Id = 2, Name="Steve"},
            new Student(){ Id = 3, Name="Ram"},
            new Student(){ Id = 4, Name="Abdul"}
        };
```

Или применительно к вашему топику.

```
 var LC = new List<MyClass>() { 
            new MyClass(){ A = "ABC", C="DIG"},
            new MyClass(){ A = "ABC1", C="DIG1"}
        };
```

Comment: Вы предлагаете вручную 300 раз написать new MyClass(){ A = "ABC1", C="DIG1"}?

Comment: Ну не знаю. Вас же не устраивает цикл. Что ещё предложить? Могу предложить подготовить список значений где либо и потом на основе него создавать нужный

Comment: но тут же Add все равно внутри вызывается :)

Comment: @Grundy человек сказал что не хочет вызывать. А то что оно там вызывается или вызываются ещё другие методы в вопросе не указано :))

Answer (score 2):

```
private class MyClass
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public MyClass() { }
    public static MyClass Get_Template_A_ABC_C_DIG() 
            => new MyClass() { A = "ABC", C = "DIG" };
    public static List<MyClass> RepeatCreate(int Count, Func<MyClass> action) 
            => Enumerable.Range(0, Count).Select(void_ => action()).ToList();
}
```

`List<MyClass> LC = MyClass.RepeatCreate(300, MyClass.Get_Template_A_ABC_C_DIG);`